# Spring 4 with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.1.3.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, are they compatible with each other? I am getting errors for example java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.proffart</groupId>
<artifactId>haybet</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>haybet Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.framework.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <!-- MySQL -->
   <dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>haybet</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's not an error AnnotationSessionFactory doesn't exist anymore in Hibernate 4.
Check this link : http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring